# std::bind vs std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, std, shared-ptr

Can't understand how to use shared_ptr binded to class function.
An error occurrs at line **USE** because compiler can't convert **shared_ptr** to **A**.

```
#include <functional>

class A {
    public:
        const bool check(void) const { return true; };
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    const std::function<const bool(const A)> f_check = &A::check;
    auto a = std::make_shared<const A>();
    auto f_check_a = std::bind(f_check, a); // line BIND
    auto res = f_check_a(); // line USE - ERROR!!!

    return 0;
}
```

I can replace line **BIND** to access real value of smart pointer:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    auto f_check = &A::check;
    auto a = std::make_shared<const A>();
    auto f_check_a = std::bind(f_check, *a.get()); // line BIND
    auto res = f_check_a(); // line USE - NO ERRORS

    return 0;
}
```

Now code is compiled and may be it will work.
But I'd like to know - is it acceptable way to use raw value from smart pointer? May I somehow use shared_ptr instead raw value?

**UPD2:**
Looks like my colleague have found a nice workaround:

```
class A {
    public:
        const bool check(void) const { return true; };
};

using p_func = const bool(A::*)() const;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    auto a = std::make_shared<const A>();
    p_func b = &A::check;
    auto f_check_a = std::bind(b, a);
    auto res = f_check_a();
}
```

Now I can send b as argument and bind to **shared_ptr**.

**UPD:**
I can't use lambda in my real task.
Here is some more code from real project:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

class Block {
    public:
        const bool check1(void) const { return false; };
        const bool check2(void) const { return false; };
        const bool check3(void) const { return false; };
};

using block_t = std::shared_ptr<const Block>;

class Worker {
    private:
        std::vector<const block_t> _container;
    public:
        void processor(const std::function<const bool(const Block)> f_check) {
            block_t my_block = nullptr;
            auto lambda = [my_block, f_check](const block_t block) mutable {
                auto function_check = std::bind(f_check, *block.get());
                if (function_check()) {
                    my_block = block;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            };
            std::find_if(_container.begin(), _container.end(), lambda);
        }
};

void test(block_t block) {
    Worker worker;
    worker.processor(&Block::check1);
    worker.processor(&Block::check2);
    worker.processor(&Block::check3);
}
```

**UPD3:**
Fixed code without smart pointer dereferencing:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

class Block {
public:
    const bool check1(void) const { return false; };
    const bool check2(void) const { return false; };
    const bool check3(void) const { return false; };
};

using block_t = std::shared_ptr<const Block>;
using p_func = const bool(Block::*)() const;

class Worker {
private:
    std::vector<const block_t> _container;
public:
    void processor(p_func f_check) {
        block_t my_block = nullptr;
        auto lambda = [my_block, f_check](const block_t block) mutable {
            auto function_check = std::bind(f_check, block);
            if (function_check()) {
                my_block = block;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        std::find_if(_container.begin(), _container.end(), lambda);
    }
};

void test(block_t block) {
    Worker worker;
    worker.processor(&Block::check1);
    worker.processor(&Block::check2);
    worker.processor(&Block::check3);
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you can't replace the `std::bind` line with a lambda.

Comment: I do not have the instance of object when I'm calling methods check1..3, on the client side I can send only a reference to a class function which should process a collection.

Comment: You do. What else is `block`? Just nest the lambda inside the other lambda.

Comment: Sorry, I need some time to understand what do you mean

Comment: Please explain _why_ you can't use lambdas. This question is tagged [tag:c++11].

Comment: I really can not figure out how to implement lambda in the test() method.

Comment: Why use `bind` at all? Just say `if (f_check(*block))` instead!

Comment: I'm using bind to avoid dereferencing smart pointer. On the other hand this code explicitly shows which instance is binding to the current check method. May be it's not as serious to dereference sp as I think, but I'd like to not use raw pointer if I can avoid it.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid dereferencing it? What for?

Comment: Raw pointers are painful. In my case I think a code must be written as safe as it possible and compiler should solve how to optimize it.

Comment: I think you're confused. How do you think `std::bind(f_check, block)` calls  the function if it doesn't dereference `block`?

Comment: It does, but it does at the time when smart pointer is valid and I've delivered a valid SP to it. When I have one exclusive SP to the object it gives me assurance - "You do right job, dude! Your object is still alive!". When I dereference SP in my code I can trace it and be sure that raw pointer is valid for all time I use it. But it breaks all the conception of safe memory management on my side. I respond for my part, STL responds for it's part. If I send valid SP to STL and STL has failed, it's a bug in STL, not in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are first creating a `std::function`, expecting an `A` instance, from a member function and than trying to bind it to a `shared_ptr`. You can skip that part:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<const A>();
auto f_check_a = std::bind(&A::check, a);
auto res = f_check_a();
```

`std::bind` knows how to directly bind a member function to a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @adnako Strange, tested with MSVC 2010 and it copiled.

Comment: I'm sorry, it really works fine. Now I need to modify this to my real use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Must you use `std::bind`? You could use a lambda instead.

```
auto f_check_a = [=]{ return a->check(); };
```

Comment: I have posted more code, check it, please. I can't use lambda in my case.

Answer (score 2):

`function` expects to get an instance of `A`, not a `shared_ptr<A>`, so the answer to your question is basically yes, I believe.

However, I would make 2 changes to your code as follows (see my comments):

```
const std::function<const bool(const A&)> f_check = &A::check; // <-- Added & after A here
auto a = std::make_shared<const A>();
auto f_check_a = std::bind(f_check, *a); // <-- no need to call get() on a
auto res = f_check_a(); // line USE - ERROR!!!
```

Comment: "<-- no need to call get() on a" - Is it not the same but a few symbols less? Check my update code, please.

Answer (score 1):

> But I'd like to know - is it acceptable way to use raw value from smart pointer?

Yes, but you can just write `*a` instead of `*a.get()`

However, the call wrapper returned from `bind` has a reference to the`A` object, so it is your responsibility to ensure the reference remains valid.  If you bound the `shared_ptr` then that would increase the reference count and keep the object alive.

> May I somehow use shared_ptr instead raw value?

If you use `std::function<const bool(const A)>` then you cannot pass a `shared_ptr<const A>`.

When you use `std::function<const bool(const A)>` you create a callable type that has exactly the call signature `const bool(const A)` and so you have to pass it an argument that is convertible to `const A`, and `shared_ptr<const A>` is not convertible to `const A`.

A workaround would be to use a lambda to combine the `std::function` and `shared_ptr`:

```
            auto function_check = [] { return f_check(*block); };
            if (function_check()) {
```

However, you are trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist, just do this instead:

```
            if (f_check(*block)) {
                my_block = block;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```

Then you don't need to `bind` anything.

Comment: Yep, I can throw out bind if I use dereferencing, thanks for example. But I'm just trying to avoid any responsibility to watch for pointers' life cycles. And looks like I found a solution, look at **UPD3** please.

Comment: That `bind` in **UPD3** is still useless.  `std::mem_fn(f_check)(*block)` would work too, or just `((*block).*f_check)()`. I don't understand why you have a phobia about dereferencing, why are you complicating your code to avoid it? `block` is passed to the closure function, its lifetime is not going to end before you dereference it. What are you worrying about?

Comment: Because dereferencing is painful for me and I do not have enough knowledge and experience about memory management in c++. I am convinced that smart pointers do not have issues with null-pointer dereferencing and I have much examples with classic pointers' access violations. I'm going to consider both ways. Thanks for advices.

Comment: _"Because dereferencing is painful for me"_ O_o wut?  If the pointer is null then the `bind` version will still dereference it and crash, it's just that the dereferencing happens in library code not in your code.

Comment: Smart Pointer can not be null in my case, because I follow simple rules. If STL needs to dereference SP it may be sure my SP is valid and no crashes can be due to _"the pointer is null"_.

Comment: Well then there's no problem saying `f_check(*block)`, so I don't understand what you're worried about.